# Interpretation of generating function infinite product

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

Let $P$ denote the set of primes and let $s\in\{-1,1\}$. How can you interpret the coefficient of $x^n$ in the power series expansion of $$\prod_{p\in P} (1+sx^p)^s$$

for either choice of $s$?
I found how to give an interpretation to $s=1$ but have no idea with $-1$.
Thank you for helping

EDIT: for s=1 i said that i can interpret the coeficient as the number of ways to pay the amount k cents with only coins of prime cents (with only one coin for each prime).

Comment: tell us how you did it for $s=1$

Comment: @UrošSlovenija i post the edit ;)

Comment: Note for $s = -1$ that $(1 - x^p)^{-1} = \sum_{k \ge 0} x^{kp}$ (so now you have more coins) ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Community wiki answer based on the comments so that the question can be marked as answered:

For $s=1$, the coefficient counts the number of ways of writing $n$ as a sum of distinct primes.

For $s=-1$, the coefficient counts the number of ways of writing $n$ as a sum of primes.